# Optimizing JS Code to Display Certain Divs when Hovered

Tags: javascript, html, css

My current goal is to display certain paragraph elements when the image area is focused/hovered over. The default display value should be "none".

I got the code to work, but only when the user hovers directly over the element. How would I optimally make this paragraph element hide/show when the area of the image tag is highlighted?

Below are my current code setups.

```js
var projImg = document.getElementsByClassName("projImg");
var projDesc = document.getElementsByClassName("projDesc");


var opacityHalf = function() {
  this.style.opacity = '0.5';
};

var opacityFull = function() {
  this.style.opacity = '1.0';
}

var displayP = function() {
  this.style.display = 'block';
}

var hideP = function() {
  this.style.display = 'none';
}

for (i = 0; i < projImg.length; i++) {
  projImg[i].addEventListener("mouseover" || "touchStart", opacityHalf, false);
}

for (i = 0; i < projImg.length; i++) {
  projImg[i].addEventListener("mouseout" || "touchEnd", opacityFull, false);
}

for (i = 0; i < projDesc.length; i++) {
  projDesc[i].addEventListener("mouseover" || "touchStart", displayP, false);
}
```

```html
<div class="projectContain">
  <div class="h3Box">
    <h3>Project<br>Description</h3>
  </div>
  <img class="projImg" src="https://picsum.photos/300/200" alt="Description">
  <p class="projDesc">Paragraph text goes here.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need JS to do this, the sane can be done with css

```
.projDesc{
  display:none;
}

.projImg:hover + .projDesc,.projImg:focus + .projDesc{
  display:block;
}
```

Here  `.projImg:hover + .projDesc` means when `.projImg:hover` happens select adjacent  `.projDesc` and

Comment: Thank you for the solution, this works fantastic! Just out of curiosity, how would one go about making this work in JavaScript form though?

Comment: @invalid- Didn't get you , can you please explain